# Calendar week base php

Tags: php

I want to make a calendar based on weeks with php found this script. If i get week 18 the first day is in april. How can i make it wright &bnsp; for the first day?

If you look at Juni there is 4 blank days in the begining of the week then i need php to print 4 &bsp;  (blank day) hope you can help.

```
$week_number = 18;
$year = 2018;

if($week_number < 10){
   $week_number = "0".$week_number;
}

for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++)
{
    echo date('d', strtotime($year."W".$week_number.$day))."\n";
}
```

Comment: what did you achieve so far?

Comment: What problem does the `&nbsp;` solve for you that isn't solved by a normal space or not printing anything?

Comment: are you interested in outputing a week or a month? You have input of week. If I want to see week 18, I would not want monday to be blank. If it was month, still not blank, maybe grey font.

Comment: I want to make a calendar now i am geting the week that starts with april 30. I want it to start with 1st that is tusday. And i want a blank space for april 30. I am usling it later in a month based calendar.

Comment: @calle.fr Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want.
I save the days in an array instead and then find the key of the lowest number (that's the start of next month).
Then I loop the array and if the key is less than the start position I echo new line, else the value.

```
for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++){
    $days[$day] = date('d', strtotime($year."W".$week_number.$day))."\n";
}
$start = array_keys($days, min($days))[0];

for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++){
    If($day<$start){
        Echo "\n";
   }Else{
        Echo $days[$day];
   }
 }
```

https://3v4l.org/dIhYZ

Answer (score -1):

Ok works good to hard for me to do myself now, but i will lern. That works for the start of the week but how it will look at the end of the week? The 31st is on a thursday.

Comment: But that is a different question. Can i make a new post of it?